# Simple schema - max value for a property storing cms text

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

Let say you are using the `Simple schema` package for meteor, and you want to have a property that will store `text content` for a CMS and you don't know how much text the user will use, what would be a good number for the max property in the `simple schema`?, and what would happen if I don't set the max property?, could I run into the problem of someone sending 1 MB of text? Would be a better idea to use a custom validation to calculate the size of the text?

```
myCMSSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  textContent : {
    type : String,
    max : 150 //<--- max?
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For string values, `max` defines the maximum string length. You can set a reasonable length there.

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#minmax

Comment: I think the question is more about what number would be a good number with a big chunk of text, instead of how to validate the number. Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly.

Comment: @ncubica  I see. I just saw "Would be a better idea to use a custom validation to calculate the size of the text?" and thought that you wanted to know how to limit it. I guess it would be important to know what sort of data you are expecting to get. Blog posts, pages of manuals? The maximum size of one document in Mongo is 16MB otherwise I don't think there is a particular cap on the size of the field.